# Firing a tag only on Homepage and another tag on any other page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup a tag that fires **only** on homepage view and a separate tag that fires on any other pages view, **except** homepage.

I tried setting the following exception triggers:

defining homepage as URL equals https://homepage.com
defining it as Pageurl matches ^https://www.homepage.ro$
defining it as Pageurl matches ^https://www.homepage.ro/$

Still, the non-homepage tag fires on homepage together with the tag for homepage

So my problem how do I separate homepage from anything else, in the simplest and most reliable GTM method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely match by Page URL if you want, but since you're looking at just doing homepage or not, I'd recommend sticking with a regular expression-free Page Path instead. You want two triggers:

### Trigger: Trigger on Homepage

[image: trigger on homepage]

### Trigger: Don't trigger on Homepage

[image: don't trigger on homepage]

Open your tags and assign either trigger to each based on your requirements.

Comment: I tried this and the non-homepage tag doesn't fire on any page at all. Not on homepage, but not on any other page either. (the homepage tag fires correctly)